# Scipy ode integrate to unknown limit of t, based on the size of solution

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am modeling charged particles moving through an electromagnetic field and am using scipy ode. The code here is simplified, obviously, but works as an example. The problem I have is that I want to end the integration after a limit on r, not on t. So, integrate dx/dt up to the point where norm(x) > r.

I don't want to just change the function to integrate over r, however, because the position is a function of t. Can I do a definite integral over an unrelated variable or something?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def RHS(state, t, Efield, q, mp):

    ds0 = state[3]
    ds1 = state[4]
    ds2 = state[5]
    ds3 = q/mp * Efield*state[0]
    ds4 = q/mp * Efield*state[1]
    ds5 = q/mp * Efield*state[2]

    r = np.linalg.norm((state[0], state[1], state[2]))

    # if r > 30000 then do stop integration.....?

    # return the two state derivatives
    return [ds0, ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4, ds5]


ts = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
state0 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Efield=1.0
q=1.0
mp=1.0

stateFinal = odeint(RHS, state0, ts, args=(Efield, q, mp))
print(np.linalg.norm(stateFinal[-1,0:2]))
```

Comment: One variant is to search for sign changes in the objective function and employ something like the secant method to refine the time of the root, as done in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2750364/115115. The general topic is "event handling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the process by performing integration step by step using [scipy.integrate.ode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html). Example:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
t_initial = 0
dt = 0.1
t_max = 10
r = ode(RHS).set_initial_value(state0, t_initial).set_f_params(Efield, q, mp)
solution = [state0]
while r.successful() and r.t < t_max:
    new_val = r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    solution.append(new_val)
    if np.linalg.norm((new_val[0], new_val[1], new_val[2])) > 30000:
        break
print(solution)
```

Note that the signature of RHS will have to be changed to `def RHS(t, state, Efield, q, mp):` for `ode`, the independent variable comes first, unlike in `odeint`.

The output is the solution computed in the increments of `dt` of independent variable, up to the time when the loop ends (either because `t_max` is reached, or integrator fails, or the condition for `break` was encountered).

Comment: This is actually really nice because I can also choose a dynamic timestep based on the current conditions. That was something else I was sweating over!