# scipy ODE, what happens when nsteps exceeded?

Tags: numpy, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am running a numerical integration using scipy ode on several million cases and occasionally I get the error:

> Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).

I increased nsteps a fair bit (500,000), and I also tried specifying the BDF method for 'stiff' problems, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973036/odd-scipy-ode-integration-error)

```
r = ode(RHS).set_initial_value(state0, t_initial).set_f_params(Efield,qmp)
r.set_integrator('vode',nsteps=500000,method='bdf')
```

My question is: what happens when this occurs? Is that integration run thrown out? Or, can I force it to be thrown out? I don't care if I lose a few out of millions of runs, but I don't want the data to be contaminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is suspect when this error occurs. As a test case, I tried integrating dy/dt = y from 0 to 1 with mere 10 steps:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
r = ode(lambda t, y: y).set_initial_value(1, 0).set_integrator('lsoda', nsteps=10)
print(r.integrate(1))
```

This prints `[1.40213975]` with the warning "Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)". The return value is clearly wrong: the exact solution is `exp(1) = 2.718...`  It seems the process of integration indeed stops when nsteps is reached, and whatever y is found by that time is returned, even if it is not y(1).

You can detect this by calling `r.successful()` after `r.integrate`: if it returns False, the most recent step failed.

Increasing nsteps (50 is enough here) eliminates the warning and returns correct value.

Aside: consider using [new SciPy API for ODE](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems) such as `solve_ivp`, which eliminate some of the micromanaging of the old `ode` method (there is no `nsteps` option in `solve_ivp`).

Comment: OK, so to clarify, the integration does not actually stop at nsteps, it keeps going until it's done and just throws a warning at nsteps?

Comment: Re-reading the code, it does terminate when reaching nsteps, so my answer was wrong. See the revision.

Comment: OK thanks. So then is there a way to throw that integration out? Or maybe I can catch that warning and throw it out manually?

Comment: On another note, I am still using the old ODE because I need to bail out based on position and not time (see my prev question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047265/scipy-ode-integrate-to-unknown-limit-of-t-based-on-the-size-of-solution)

Comment: Just check  `r.successful()` after each `r.integrate`. Edited in the answer.